# DBMS_ROWID.rowid_info not working properly

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this PL-Sql Code that is not working fine.
But, as far as i know, is supposed to work.
Database is Oracle 11g.

```
DECLARE
l_rowid_in         ROWID;
l_rowid_type       NUMBER;
l_object_number    NUMBER;
l_relative_fno     NUMBER;
l_block_number     NUMBER;
l_row_number       NUMBER;
BEGIN

SELECT ROWID INTO l_rowid_in FROM TABLENAME  a 
WHERE RECORD_ID_CALL_STR_ID = 'dummystring'
AND ROWNUM < 2;

dbms_rowid.rowid_info(rowid_in       =>l_rowid_in     ,
                      rowid_type     =>l_rowid_type   ,
                      object_number  =>l_object_number,
                      relative_fno   =>l_relative_fno ,
                      block_number   =>l_block_number ,
                      row_number     =>l_row_number   );
dbms_output.put_line('object_number ='||l_object_number);
END;
/
```

When i run this script using, toad it give me error

```
Error at line 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: a line 11
```

Can anybody help me? It's a weird behaviour, thank you.

Comment: What is the datatype and size of `RECORD_ID_CALL_STR_ID`?

Comment: Additional informations
1) RECORD_ID_CALL_STR_ID is a VARCHAR2
2) If i run a SELECT ROWID AS DUMMYALIAS etc it returns values
3) Table is partitioned

Comment: Your code runs fine for me on both partitioned and non-partitioned tables. What happens if you change it to run against a non-partitioned table?

Comment: I found the solution. The table is partitioned and is a IOT. So the rowid will change almost every time and you can't access to this.